# Update Two Tables -error - Unknown column 'product_varities.product_varities_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to update two tables, taking data from one table and updating the second table. However I keep getting error:

> 1054 - Unknown column exception in MySQL.

```
Orderlines
orderlinesid
quantity
product_varities_id (fk)

Product Varities
product_varities_id (pk)
quantity
```

**Stored Proc:**

```
BEGIN
DECLARE quantityToAddBack int(5);

select orderlines.quantity from orderlines where orderlines.order_id = iorderid AND product_varities.product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid into quantityToAddBack;
-- do update FIRST
UPDATE orderlines set orderlines.`status_id` = 2
WHERE orderlines.order_id = iorderid AND orderlines.product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid;

-- then update quantity
update product_varities set product_varities.quantity = product_varities.quantity + quantityToAddBack
WHERE product_varities.product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid;

END
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I am executing two statements because from my research on here I found you cannot update two tables at once.

Comment: Please share the DDL of the tables, the query does not look correct and cant predict unless the DDL is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given description looks like `iorderid` and `iproductvaritiesid` are input values to the procedure.

So the queries inside the procedure should be as

```
select 
ol.quantity into quantityToAddBack
from orderlines ol
join product_varities pv on pv.product_varities_id = ol.product_varities_id
where ol.order_id = iorderid ;

-- do update FIRST
UPDATE orderlines set `status_id` = 2
WHERE order_id = iorderid 
AND product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid;


-- then update quantity
update 
product_varities 
set quantity = quantity + quantityToAddBack
WHERE product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid;
```

Comment: Can you explain why the need for a join in the select into statement?

Comment: In your select query you have something else `AND product_varities.product_varities_id = iproductvaritiesid into quantityToAddBack` meaning you are tying to match data in `roduct_varities` table while selecting data from `Orderlines` this needs joining the table.

Comment: In the Select, I need two conditions in the where clause where ol.order_id = iorderid AND ol.product_varities_id = iproductvarities... but it does not work... what do about this?

Comment: Are you getting any error, if the value is input then it should not give errors or its not returning data?

Comment: I fixed it, I had to store the product_varities_id into a local variable and use that within the updates.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will accept your answer as I did make the mistake of not joining which lead me to correct my errors.